# Animation Transition Speed

Tags: java, android

So I have this code which moves an image left to right, but it is positioned 1/4 down the page, so not middle or left, which rule is best for me to use to move it in a straight line horizontally?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(getSystemUiFlags());
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page);

    homeLayout = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.HomeLayout);
    homeLayout.setOnTouchListener(new RelativeLayout.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                moveButton();
                return true;
            }
        }
    );
}

public void moveButton() {
    View plane = findViewById(R.id.AreoplaneImg);

    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(homeLayout);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    params.width = 700;
    params.height = 90;
    plane.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

Secondly is there anyway of slowing down the transition from right to left, as it is too quick?

Comment: What is PositionPlane class? and is this question related to CSS?

Comment: I really don't understand this question? What exactly are you asking? Are you using a `Transition`? Are you animating yourself? How is the `RelativeLayout` rule related to what you are doing? How is css related to your question? What exactly are you doing? Please give us more information...

Comment: PositionPlane is a class @NikoYuwono. RelativeLayout.LayoutParams PositionPlane = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

Comment: hi @XaverKapeller, i have an image which i call in my code and it moves from left to right using the RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rule.

Comment: @XaverKapeller i have put the whole code for you to see.

Comment: What do you mean? How does it move from the left to the right? Are you animating it or not? And exactly do you want to know? What is the problem?

Comment: So you are performing a `Transition`. Why aren't you just a normal `ObjectAnimator`? If you don't know what you are doing you shouldn't jump straight into using `Transition`s.

Comment: @XaverKapeller the problem is the aeroplane image starts off 1/4 of the page down, i want it to be animated so it moves across the page from right to left, which it does, but it moves across going to the upper left hand corner of the page. How do i move it across the page in a straight horizontal line, using the AddRule?

Comment: You are doing so many things wrong... I fixed the coding conventions in the code in your question, hope you don't mind... Why are you using a `OnTouchListener`? Why not an `OnClickListener`? The click listener is what you want. If you assign an `OnTouchListener` to a `View` you destroy a lot of functionality which the `View` would normally do for you. Only do that if you know what you are doing and have a reason to do it. Why are you setting the `LayoutParams` in such a weird way? Why are you trying to animate a `Button` in such a complicated way? Why not just use an `ObjectAnimator`?

Comment: And you are setting the rule all wrong in the first place? If you use `ALIGN_LEFT` you have to supply the id of the `View` you want to use as a reference. Not `RelativeLayout.TRUE`. And from what I could gather `ALIGN_LEFT` is not at all what you want. `ALIGN_LEFT` is a rule which means that the left edge of the `View` will match the left edge of the referenced `View`. What you probably want is `ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT` which means the the `View` will be aligned with the left edge of its parent.

Comment: And if you use `beginDelayedTransition()` you can pass a `Transition` instance as a second parameter and on that you can set the duration of the animation, but as I said, you can just use an `ObjectAnimator`, you don't need to bother using `Transition`s. Is there any reason at all you want to use a `Transition`?

Comment: Also for some reason you are setting the width and height on the `LayoutParams`? Why? Just remove those two lines you don't need them. Set the height and width in `dp` in your layout. But **NEVER** hardcode specific pixel values in your code unless you know what you are doing and have a good reason for it. Only use `dp` when you have to set the size of a `View`. All the bad things that come from setting a size in pixels and not `dp` are too long and too many to explain in comments but be sure, there are a lot of them...

Comment: Also you should make all your `findViewById()` calls in `onCreate()`. That `View plane = findViewById(...)` call in the `moveButton()` method should actually be in `onCreate` and `plane` should be a field just like `homeLayout`.

Comment: hi @XaverKapeller, i was just following a tutorial which showed me what to do, i am a beginner to java. I had to put size due to the fact the plane grew at the end of the animation for some reason, i don't think it keeps the size i set in the XML.

Comment: @Raj yeah it doesn't keep the size because of the way you are setting the `LayoutParams`. Forget about `Transition`s, forget about `LayoutParams` and `RelativeLayout` rules. You don't need any of that. Just use a simple `ObjectAnimator` with a click listener.